# Heroku Connect / Salesforce Opportunity Type

Tags: node.js, heroku, salesforce

**Development**: NodeJS, postgresql

**Challenge**: In Salesforce there is an Opportunity table with a column Type. This is a *picklist* and I am attempting to find what table stores these *picklist* values.

**Research**: I was able to find using Heroku Connect a mapping to a Salesforce object *PicklistValueInfo*

**Problem(s)**:

1. I am not sure if this is the correct object to connect
2. When I attempt to create a mapping it doesn't get past the message:

> Querying Salesforce for PicklistValueInfo fields ...

**DevTools**: When I look under DevTools it appears it's throwing the following errors.

```
fetch-utils.js:9 Cannot read property 'unsyncable' of undefined

fetch-utils.js:10 TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsyncable' of undefined
    at r (create-edit-mapping.jsx:42)
    at t.value (create-edit-mapping.jsx:455)
    at l._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:799)
    at l._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:822)
    at l._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:746)
    at l._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:724)
    at l.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:645)
    at l.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:547)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:125)
    at l._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:754)
    at l._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:724)
    at l.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:645)

create-edit-mapping.jsx:257 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
    at t.value (create-edit-mapping.jsx:257)
    at l._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:799)
    at l._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:822)
    at l._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:746)
    at l._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:724)
    at l.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:645)
    at l.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:547)
    at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:125)
    at l._updateRenderedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:754)
    at l._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:724)
    at l.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:645)
```

**Questions**:

1. Am I on the right path attempting to map to *PicklistValueInfo*?
2. If I am **NOT** on the right path are there any suggestions on where I should be looking?

Comment: Can you file a support ticket with Heroku? https://help.heroku.com/

Comment: I have submitted a support ticket with Heroku and they are looking into it. I noticed in your profile you a **Platform Evangelist at Salesforce.com**. Am I on the right path attempting to map to _PicklistValueInfo_?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. There should be some way to sync pick list values but I haven't looked into how to do that with Heroku Connect.

Comment: Heroku Connect was able to fix the errors, however I am still getting the following message when attempting to connect: `Unable to load fields for Salesforce object 'PicklistValueInfo' of connection: 95bcf900-a93c-44c5-8b84-27b41343b615`. Heroku is thinking this is some permissions error on the Salesforce side. Would you have any ideas or know anyone that might be able to help with this?

Comment: One option is to try as the same user to get that data via [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or you could contact your Salesforce Account manager.

Comment: So are the Picklist Values for the object Opportunity Type always going to be: _New Customer, Existing Customer - Downgrade, Existing Customer - Replacement, Existing Customer - Upgrade_?